# Navegação utilizando setas do teclado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Preciso realizar uma navegação na DOM através das setas de teclado. Consigo realizar ela quando a mesma vai apenas em duas direções (cima ou baixo, frente ou trás), porém para movimentar nas quatro direções não achei uma forma. Preciso que essa navegação leve em consideração somente um determinado seletor, no caso a tag '`<a>`' Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte:

```
<body>
    <a href="#">teste</a> <a href="#">TESTE</a> <a href="#">teste</a> <a href="#">TESTE</a><br/>
    <a href="#">teste</a> <a href="#">TESTE</a> <a href="#">teste</a> <a href="#">TESTE</a><br/>
    <a href="#">teste</a> <a href="#">TESTE</a> <a href="#">teste</a> <a href="#">TESTE</a><br/>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).keydown(function(e){
          switch (e.keyCode)
          {
            //esquerda
            case 37:
              var elAtivo    = document.activeElement;
              var elAnterior = $(elAtivo).prevAll('a').first();

              $(elAnterior).focus();
            break;
            //cima
            case 38:
            break;
            //direita
            case 39:
              var elAtivo   = document.activeElement;
              var elProximo = $(elAtivo).nextAll('a').first();
              $(elProximo).focus();
            break;
            //baixo
            case 40:
            break;

          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Poderia postar o código que possui até o momento?

Comment: Editei a pergunta para exibir como o código está atualmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível realizar [pegando as coordenadas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28222246/7385033) dos itens em questão e verificando quais estariam mais próximos.

Eu criei uma função para pegar as coordenadas e implementei os movimentos para cima e para baixo que faltavam no seu caso.

Seria interessante adotar o mesmo padrão para todos os casos, dessa forma independeria da sequência dos itens no `HTML`, mas sim da sua posição na tela.

Segue o código:

```
<body>
  <a href="#">1</a> <a href="#">2</a> <a href="#">3</a> <a href="#">4</a><br/>
  <a href="#">5</a> <a href="#">6</a> <a href="#">7</a> <a href="#">8</a><br/>
  <a href="#">9</a> <a href="#">10</a> <a href="#">11</a> <a href="#">12</a><br/>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).keydown(function (e) {
        const elAtivo = document.activeElement;
        const as = [].slice.call($('a'));

        switch (e.keyCode) {
          //esquerda
          case 37:
            var elAnterior = $(elAtivo).prevAll('a').first();
            $(elAnterior).focus();
            break;
          //cima
          case 38:
            let elProximoCima;

            as.forEach(el => {
              if (elProximoCima === undefined)
                elProximoCima = el
              if (getOffset(el).top < getOffset(elAtivo).top &&
                getOffset(elAtivo).top - getOffset(el).top <= getOffset(elAtivo).top - getOffset(elProximoCima).top) {
                if (Math.abs(getOffset(el).left - getOffset(elAtivo).left) <=
                  Math.abs(getOffset(elProximoCima).left - getOffset(elAtivo).left))
                  elProximoCima = el
              }
            });

            $(elProximoCima).focus();
            break;
          //direita
          case 39:
            var elProximo = $(elAtivo).nextAll('a').first();
            $(elProximo).focus();
            break;
          //baixo
          case 40:
            let elProximoBaixo;

            as.forEach(el => {
              if (elProximoBaixo === undefined)
                elProximoBaixo = el
                if (getOffset(el).top > getOffset(elAtivo).top &&
                getOffset(el).top - getOffset(elAtivo).top >= getOffset(elProximoBaixo).top - getOffset(elAtivo).top) {
                if (Math.abs(getOffset(el).left - getOffset(elAtivo).left) <=
                  Math.abs(getOffset(elProximoBaixo).left - getOffset(elAtivo).left))
                  elProximoBaixo = el
              }
            });
            $(elProximoBaixo).focus();
            break;

        }
      });
    });

    function getOffset(el) {
      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        left: rect.left + window.scrollX,
        top: rect.top + window.scrollY
      };
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Também inseri um `CSS` para ficar mais visual a mudança:

```
<style>
    a {
      margin: 30px;
    }

    a:focus {
      color: red;
    }
</style>
```